# Can question be deleted after answering and accepting?

Tags: support

something strange just happened.
Someone asks question. I gave answer. They accepted.
little later, the question is gone.

How is this possible? And who deleted it? Can OP delete the question after it was answered and accepted?

I Do not care about virtual points. I am just wondering what happened, and what is the policy of the site on this. that is all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is strange - looking in the obvious places (e.g. @Muro user page) it's as if the question never existed.  Presumably he/she deleted the question after it was answered.

Comment: I thought it was impossible to delete a question after it was accepted - but perhaps it's possible if the user deletes their account or something?

Comment: The post may be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249252/i-want-to-adjust-this-code-for-below-matrix -- Your answer was unaccepted with no upvotes. Deletion is allowed under those conditions.

Comment: I voted to undelete.  Others may do so.  Some people don't like their stuff out there, in public.  You can choose to respect that, or not.  A counterargument could be made that you give up the right to privacy by posting on a public space.  It doesn't seem a particularly problematic post, unless it's illegal in some way.

Comment: hi @MichaelE2  it was still on the screen but on another monitor that I did not refresh, so I was able to take screen shot.    I do not understand what you mean by the rest of what you said. My answer was accepted by OP as you can see.

Comment: The OP unnaccepted it, which they can do at any time.  Then, after that, they deleted it.

Comment: So one can delete a question if it is answered? but not accepted?    Why would one accept an answer, then unaccept it then delete it? Very strange. In this case, how to prevent this? otherwise, any one can post question, have others answer it, then delete the question. Seems like waste of time then to answer questions.

Comment: Yes, it's a waste of time.  I think if the answer is either upvoted or accepted, then the question cannot be deleted. (The [timeline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/249252/timeline) does not show an accept or unaccept. Maybe I'm wrong. The question currently shows your answer as unaccepted. Can you see the link I posted above?)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Yes, I see it now, before I got an error. Strange. He must then unaccepted it afterwords as you said in order just to delete it.  There are very strange people in this world.    This makes it waste to time to answer questions and try to help, since it can be deleted and gone.  Something is not right here.

Comment: Rather than a glass half-full or half-empty kind of person, I’m more of a “Hey!  Someone’s been drinking out of that glass!”  kind of person.  Therefore, I suspect that many times such people who delete their questions after good answers don’t want their peers or supervisors to know they didn’t solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Usually a homework question - then erasing the trail...

Comment: @MichaelE2 That looks like a low quality question we should be actively closing and purging. Undeletion is an option when OP asks a good question and someone has put in hours of work into the answer only to see the OP cover up and delete it, but it doesn't apply here IMO. I understand folks wanting to help others and post answers to any question no matter its quality, but the reality is that such generosity comes with negative consequences for the site.

Comment: @rm-rf - Well said. I have gotten perilously close to just not bothering to look at the site anymore, since it seems in the past couple of years to have become overloaded with homework and/or zero code shown questions.

Comment: @rm-rf I agree with your assessment of the quality, but I think the larger battle against the negative consequences is irretrievably lost. A large segment of the community seem to want to help all those who seek it. Time to move on, imo: live it, live with it, or leave, I guess. In this case, I don't like that the OP took advantage of Nasser and that the OP is trying to hide the fact. I'd rather see the Q undeleted so that the OP can worry about it being discovered, Nasser's answer get a single upvote so the Q&A can't be deleted, and the question get downvoted by all who care to participate.